# I don't want my Google Map to zoom to extent after user has zoomed in

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created a map found here: http://userpages.flemingc.on.ca/~eluli/collab.html

Users can toggle between the different layers on the map. As you can see, whenever a user toggles at a new layer, the map extents to the new layer. How can I make so that this does NOT happen? For example, if a user has zoomed into a specific area, I want the map to remain at the same extent whenever a new layer is checked on.

I have written code which has the initial map extents (I deleted the extent in order to experiment but when I did that, the map does not show up).

```
function initialize() {
    var ontario = new google.maps.LatLng(49.2867873, -84.7493416);

var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: ontario,
styles: ....


var kmlOptions = {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,  
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map
};

    //Layer 0   
         layers [0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkVGVwdnEtS1puTlE&export=download',
 {preserveViewport: false, suppressInfoWindows: true});

   //Layer 1   
        layers [1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkdE9DRmxzRHdCN28&export=download',
 {preserveViewport: false, suppressInfoWindows: true});
.........................
```

Let me know if I need to show more of my code

Comment: We need a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue in the question (not a link to a broken page.  (`{preserveViewport: true}` will keep KmlLayer from zooming to fit its contents)

Answer (score 1):

`{preserveViewport: true}` will keep KmlLayer from zooming to fit its contents